# How to use multi level hierarchy names in MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012, mdx-query

I need to use the dimension field under the 2 hierarchies i.e., one hierarchy under another hierarchy in the MDX query.

Am having the below hierarchies/data in my cube:

[image]

I need to use the highlighted **[Country]** field in the MDX query.

Please find the query I have tried.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS [Geography].[Geography].[Country].currentmember.membervalue
select [Measures].[Expression1] on Columns from [Adventure Works]
```

Am getting below error:
[image]

But when am using the same syntax for a single hierarchy it works.

Please find the query and its result

[image]

```
WITH MEMBER 
[Measures].[Expression1] AS [Geography].[Country].currentmember.membervalue
select [Measures].[Expression1] on Columns from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Am expecting the same result using the two hierarchy names of the field.

Can anyone please guide me to get the required value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `WITH` or `currentmember` or membervalue` at all.

These two queries ought to list you the items within each hierarchy's level...

```
select {[Geography].[Country].members} on Columns from [Adventure Works]

select {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].members} on Columns from [Adventure Works]
```